# The Chinese hypothesis revisited

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences, prime-factorization

In the past I tried to get different variations of the so-called Chinese hypothesis, see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_hypothesis) (a disproven conjecture).

Today I wanted to combine in an artificious way also Wilson-Lagrange theorem to prove next claim.

**Claim.** If $n$ is prime then $$((n-1)!+3)^n\equiv 2\text{ mod }n.\tag{1}$$

*Sketch of the proof.* It is obvious from Wilson-Lagrange $LHS\equiv 2\cdot 2^{\varphi(n)}\text{ mod }n$, where $\varphi(n)$ is the Euler's totient.$\square$

> **Question.** I don't know if it is obvious that:
>
> *If an integer* $n$ *satisfies*  $((n-1)!+3)^n\equiv 2\text{ mod }n$ *then* $n$ *is a prime number.*
>
> Can you find such easy proof for previous statement, or well refute it with a conunterexample? **Thanks in advance.**

Now I'm stuck about how to prove it, if is right. I tested the first few integers with this code

`mod(((n-1)!+3)^n, n), from n=1 to 100`

using [Wolfram Alpha online calculator.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)

Comment: If some user is interested in the past I tried to get variations of the Chinese hypothesis writing different arithmetical functions $a(n)$ instead of $n$ in the statement of the Chinese hypothesis. I say this, if some user is interested to explore it.

Comment: By the binomial expansion your expression is always congruent to $3^n+(n-1)!^n \bmod n $.

Comment: Also, if $ n $ is not a prime then the second term is $0 $ and you are left to prove that $3^n $ is not $2 $.

Comment: By the way, use **\mod n** to generate $\mod n$ or use **\pmod n** to generate the modulus with parantheses, i.e. $\pmod n$.

Comment: Mnay thanks @user477343

Comment: No problem :) ${}$

Comment: Now I see where was confused, if $n\neq 4$ is composite then $(n-1)!\equiv 0\text{ mod n}$ as you say. Many thanks @ArnaudMortier

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One counterexample is $n=2929 = 29\times 101$.

Note that $2928! = 0 \mod 2929$, so the given statement is equivalent to  $3^{2929} = 2 \mod{2929}$.  This can be checked by computer, although checking by hand is feasible by use of the Chinese Remainder Theorem and Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: The statement is equivalent to $3^n=2\mod n $ in all non-prime cases.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.